# Which is correct: "new features in" or "new features of"?

Tags: prepositions, adjectival-phrases

Which of the following sentences is correct?

> - The new features of the software are given below
> - The new features in the software are given below

Comment: Grammatically, they are both correct. By this [Google Ngram,](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=features+in+the+software%2C+features+of+the+software&year_start=2000&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) it appears that "of the software" is used more often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in a comment, both are grammatical, and  [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=features+in+the+software%2C+features+of+the+software&year_start=2000&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) for *features in the software, features of the software* shows that  “features of the software” occurs in books far more often than does the other form.

Also consider saying  “The software's new features are given below:”,  “The software's new features include”, etc.

Note, if you specify a version number, then *in* may be better than *on*.  Eg,  “New features in software release 14.03 include:”.

Answer (score 2):

It is important to understand that the frequency of a word or phrase is not directly connected to its appropriate use. The appropriate use is decided by the context.

**in** the software indicates that the feature is with**in**/**in**side the software, e.g. a reduced amount of code or a more efficient algorithm

**of** the software is a broader - it means "associated with the software". Here it is possible that what is meant is there is added user functionality.